# My Laptop (Alienware M17x R3) keeps overheating on 14.04 (LTS) while W7 keeps it cool

Tags: 14.04, ati, xubuntu, laptop, overheating

I've installed **Xubuntu** on my laptop, because I love it, but about 30 minutes in it becomes so incredibly hot that I am scared to keep it running, lest I burn out all of the circuitry. I hope there's someone out there who knows how to fix this problem, because I do prefer Xubuntu over windows, otherwise.

I got a prefab version with

- 2.33GHz i7
- 8GB DDR3
- ATI HD6xxxM with 1GB (or 2? I'd have to check)

All in all, it feels as if it's just running the processor at full blast continuously, maybe the GPU as well? I don't know too much about hardware. I'm okay with software but I really don't know what to tell you that might be relevant other than this.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `top` to identify processes which are consuming power. You can also install `powertop` for power consumers. If there are none, try using laptop-mode-utils:

`sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`

Then edit the file  `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf` and set this:
`BATT_CPU_MAXFREQ=medium
BATT_CPU_MINFREQ=slowest
BATT_CPU_GOVERNOR=powersave
BATT_CPU_IGNORE_NICE_LOAD=1
LM_AC_CPU_MAXFREQ=fastest
LM_AC_CPU_MINFREQ=slowest
LM_AC_CPU_GOVERNOR=performance
LM_AC_CPU_IGNORE_NICE_LOAD=1
NOLM_AC_CPU_MAXFREQ=fastest
NOLM_AC_CPU_MINFREQ=slowest
NOLM_AC_CPU_GOVERNOR=performance
NOLM_AC_CPU_IGNORE_NICE_LOAD=0`

To check the actual temperature of youre chipsets, do `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`, then `sudo lm-sensors`, when asked for automatic module load say yes, and restart for the modules to be loaded.

Then just type `sensors` into a terminal to see your chipset temperatures.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input! Although I've not yet fixed my problem, at least I've determined that my graphics card is the thing that's causing all the fuss. Using sensors, it told me that my CPU is staying nice 'n fresh around 50°C while my graphics card reports 102°C. Also, this is after roughly 15 minutes of mostly just idling. Would you have any more ideas on what I should do? Powertop settings seem to be completely ignored by the card — although I'm not sure. I'll check again once it's cooled down a bit.

Comment: This is a great hint. Have you tried installing proprietary drivers? I found out that this laptop has a Geforce GTX 460M.
Try installing using this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked! after installing the fglrx drivers it's staying at a nice 'n fresh 55°C average. Idling, obviously. I hadn't tried it yet, because the same steps brought my PC to a glitchy halt earlier, so I was kinda scared to, but it worked like a charm on my laptop! :D

Comment: If it worked, please be so kind to mark my answer as resolving answer, thanks.

Comment: Whoa, derp, sorry!I'm new to this :)